# Umbraco surface controller not submitting to backend with POST

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, surface-controller

I basically have a contact form, which I need to POST to my Umbraco backend. The frontend looks similar to this:

```
using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("HandleFormSubmit", "ContactForm", FormMethod.Post)) {
    <form>
        <input name="Name" type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
}
```

I then have a surface controller in `/Controllers/ContactFormController.cs` that looks like:

```
public class ContactFormController : SurfaceController {
    // GET: ContactForm
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return PartialView("ContactForm", new ContactForm());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HandleFormSubmit(ContactForm model) {
        return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
}
```

I am trying to hit the `HandleFormSubmit` POST method. The GET method works (breakpoint proves that). No matter what I do, I cannot get it to hit this method. I've looked at tons of guides and all of them seem to be the exact same as this.

The POST data is as follows:

```
url: /contact-us/
data: name="Test"
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

What am I doing wrong here? Using Umbraco 7.6.6

Comment: The url for the post should be something like `/umbraco/sufrace/ContactForm/HandleFormSubmit`. Do you have a custom route for `/contact-us/`?

Comment: @DZL My RouteConfig.cs has not been modified no. This is Umbraco, so Umbraco handles it for me.

Comment: Yes but then you need to post to `/umbraco/sufrace/ContactForm/HandleFormSubmit` and not to `/contact-us/`

Comment: @DZL How do I tell that to the Html.BeginUmbracoForm?

Comment: What is generated when you view source in the browser?

Comment: Or alternatively, how do I make the route automatically work?

Comment: @DZL `<form action="/contact-us/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"></form>` (without the input, submit, etc.)

Comment: That's where your problem is, you don't need <form> and </form> inside the body. Loose that and it should work.

Comment: @DZL Huh that's weird. Works now :O Thanks a lot! The HTML is the same haha.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you are rendering form inside the form.

Your view should look like this:

```
using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("HandleFormSubmit", "ContactForm", FormMethod.Post)) {
    <input name="Name" type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
}
```

And it should work.

Comment: Weird how it produces the same HTML (as far as I can see), but it now works lol. Thanks again!

Comment: It's not the same HTML when you have form inside of the form ;)