# Umbraco 12 Surface Controller POST Method - unable to hit controller action

Tags: umbraco, .net-7.0, umbraco12

I am pretty new to Umbraco and am using Umbraco 12.  I have a surface controller that has a couple of Get endpoints which when sending requests to via Postman work, and a Post endpoint that I continually get a 400 Bad Request from.

The code below is a cut down version of the controller

```
[Controller]
public class EventsController : SurfaceController
{
    private readonly IPublishedContentQuery _contentQuery;

    public EventsController(
        IUmbracoContextAccessor umbracoContextAccessor,
        IUmbracoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory,
        ServiceContext services, AppCaches appCaches,
        IProfilingLogger profilingLogger,
        IPublishedUrlProvider publishedUrlProvider,
        IPublishedContentQuery contentQuery)
        : base(umbracoContextAccessor,
            databaseFactory,
            services,
            appCaches,
            profilingLogger,
            publishedUrlProvider)
    {
        _contentQuery = contentQuery;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetPlacements(int year, string titleEvent)
    {
        // Redacted - Can hit when going to its url
        https://localhost:44322/umbraco/surface/events/GetPlacements
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostPlacement(string teamName, string iso3, string finalPlacement, string titleEvent, string eventYear)
    {
        var rootContent = _contentQuery.ContentAtRoot().ToList();
        var placementItems = rootContent.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Data")!.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Event Placements");

        // redacted - Cannot hit when going to its url
        // https://localhost:44322/umbraco/surface/events/PostPlacement 

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I have looked around and see that I need to send it as either form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded

The problems as I see it

[image]

1. I dont have a lot of experience with Umbraco so its possible I have missed something pretty obvious.
2. I havent added a validator so not sure why I am getting a 400 bad request
3. I have tried adding [FromForm] in the method to the parameters and still not working
4. I have not yet tried binding it to a model
5. I have tried adding a route but then I get a 404
6. I have also seen this [Umbraco surface controller not submitting to backend with POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46646375/umbraco-surface-controller-not-submitting-to-backend-with-post) and am trying this at the same time, but still no luck.

The need for this is that this endpoint will be send data from external systems and then I have a View that is being hit, that will then present the data (That bit does work).

Answer (score 2):

**Different points to consider**

1. Direct answer : Decorate your action's method with `[Http, IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` attributes and it should work (keep me posted).

WHY

2. `SurfaceControllers` are very special controllers deeply linked to Umbraco's behaviors. Therefore, they have special behaviors. A lot of things are done for you behind the scene. And in this case, by default, `SurfaceControllers` are designed to work with an HTML FORM containg an Antiforgery Token.

In Umbraco documentation (https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/routing/surface-controllers/) when you read :

> Is used for interacting with the front-end of Umbraco (not the backoffice)

You must anderstand : "Is used for interacting with A PAGE (CONTENT) THAT HAS BEEN GENERATED BY UMBRACO AND USE SOME UMBRACO'S FEATURES (not the backoffice)"

In that context, your controller has a `this.UmbracoContext.PublishedRequest` property containing the `IPublishedContent` of the calling page.

3. Regarding your need

> The need for this is that this endpoint will be send data from
> external systems

The documentation should contains `SurfaceControllers` are not designed to create API (Application 2 Application). **They are designed for Page (content) 2 `SurfaceController` API**.

When you use a surface controller for A2A API, then `this.UmbracoContext.PublishedRequest` property is `null` (and many other things are not working).

To create real A2A API (REST or not) :

- create a basic ASP Net controller
- Use dependency injection to get your services (not all the services are available : you are not in the context of a page's call).
- depending of your version of Umbraco, you may have to set a custom route.

Comment: Apologies for the very late reply. I didnt see this response in time and havent been back on stack for a while. 

I have resolved the issue by using an API controller after looking through the docs and stumbling across it. The data that I wanted is interacting with umbraco published content but not from within a form within umbraco hense why it wasnt working.  I have upvoted your answer as it is similar to what approach I had to take